# Не везде работает Ctrl+Enter для отправки

Tags: поддержка

Не работает отправка с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

- Ответа на вопрос.
- Нового вопроса.
- Меток, отредактированных инлайн.
- Редактирование описания метки

Работает:

- Редактирование вопроса
- Редактирование ответа

Comment: А она должна работать? Вопросы/ответы и т.п. - это всё же не электронные письма и не сообщения в чате.

Comment: @NormalHuman: дело в том, что при редактировании — работает.

Comment: На сетевой мете: [Allow to submit an answer with ctrl+enter](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/189203)

Answer (score 1):

Действительно, где-то такая фича есть, а где-то нет. Предлагаю самый быстрый вариант ей на замену: <kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> (последовательно, а не вместе):

- В вопросе <kbd>Tab</kbd> переносит курсор в строку меток, откуда работает просто <kbd>Enter</kbd>
- В ответе <kbd>Tab</kbd> переносит курсор на синюю кнопку «Отправьте ваш ответ», где <kbd>Enter</kbd> ведет к логичным результатам.

Если вам удобно пользоваться горячими клавишами, обратите внимание на соответствующий чекбокс на странице параметров своей учетной записи. Там много интересного.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]